# pointer arithmetic - Getting a desired next address from a given address

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

When I execute the program I expect the address to be `0xffc10004`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t *a = (uint32_t *)0xFFC10004;
    printf("%p\n",(a+ 0x40));
    return 0;
}
```

But the result I get is `0xFFC10104`

When I replace `0x40` with `0x10` I get the expected address `0xffc10004`. Can anyone explain the reason?

Comment: _Hi When I execute the program I expect the address to be 0Xffc10004_.  I expect that you mean _Hi When I execute the program I expect the address to be 0Xffc10008_?  (i.e. `0Xffc10004 + sizeof(uint32_t) == 0Xffc10008`

Answer (score 1):

Since `a` is a pointer to `uint32_t`, `a+0x40` points to a location which stands `0x40` `uint32_t` (`0x100` bytes) after `a`, not `0x40` bytes after the address stored in `a`.

Pointer arithmetic takes in consideration the size of the elements a pointer is supposed to point at.

Imagine `a` actually points to a `uint32_t` inside an array; if `a+2`
didn't consider the whole elements but the bytes, then this would lead
to designating half the previous integer and half the next! Fortunately
this is not the case because it actually designates another integer
situated two elements (eight bytes here) further.

If you actually want to count individual bytes, you should use
a pointer to `uint8_t` (or `char`).

Answer (score 1):

In your post you state: *When I execute the program I expect the address to be 0Xffc10004*

But then you start off with:

```
uint32_t *a = (uint32_t *)0xFFC10004;
```

Did you mean `uint32_t *a = (uint32_t *)0xFFC10000;` ?

Based on the assumption of a typo in your code segment the following will use `(uint32_t *)0xFFC10000`.

But first Keep in mind that the value `0x40` is not the same as `0x4`

```
    0x40; == 64
    0x4;  == 4 (use this one if you want to see a 4 byte change)
```

When incrementing a pointer type, the distance from one location to the next sequential location is always `sizeof(type)`. For example:

```
a + 1 == a + sizeof(uint32_t)
a + 0x40 == a + 0x40*sizeof(uint32_t)
```

etc.

This will illustrate:

```
uint32_t *p = (uint32_t *)0xFFC10000;//starting with value intended in post (not 0xFFC10000)
printf("base location: \t\t%p\n", p);    // base location of p
printf("base location + 0x4:\t%p\t(%p + 0x4*sizeof(uint32_t))\n", p+0x4, p);    // adds 4*sizeof(uint32_t) to base location  of p
printf("base location + 0x40:\t%p\t(%p + 0x40*sizeof(uint32_t))\n", p+0x40, p); // adds 0x40*sizeof(uint32_t) to base location  of p
printf("base location + 1:\t%p\t(%p + sizeof(uint32_t))\n", p+0x1, p);          // adds 1*sizeof(uint32_t) to base location of p
```

Outputs the values as indicated above:

[image]